# Analogy of the mean value theorem?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on the open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ of class $C^1$. Given $a \in U$ is $\epsilon >0$, show that there exist $\delta >0$ such that $x,y \in U, |x-a|< \delta, |y-a|< \delta \Rightarrow f(y)-f(x) = f'(a)(y-x) + r(x,y)$ where $|r(x,y)| \leq \epsilon|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(y) - f(x) - f'(a)(y-x) = \int_0^1 \Bigl(f'\bigl(x+t(y-x)\bigr) - f'(a)\Bigr)\,dt\cdot (y-x)$$

for $x,y$ close enough to $a$. Now use the continuity of $f'$.

Comment: How does it include $f '(a)$ within the integral, without being affected?
I understand that $f(y)-f(x)= \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x+t(y-x)) (y-x)) dt$
but not the other of $f'(a)$, could you explain it to me please?

Comment: $f'(a)$ is a constant, so $\int_0^1 f'(a)\,dt = f'(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, I'd have to $r(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x+t(y-x))-f'(a))dt . (y-x)$, Is that where I use continuity, or am I wrong? would I use continuity to show that $|r(x,y)| < \varepsilon |x-y|$?

Comment: Yes, you use continuity of $f'$ to show that for $x,y$ close enough to $a$ the integrand $f'(x + t(y-x)) - f'(a)$ has norm less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: by the continuity of f '  we have to for everything $\varepsilon>0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that if $||x-a||< \delta$ it implies $||f'(x)-f'(a)||< \varepsilon$. but since I include the integral to prove that $|| \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x+t(y-x)) - f'(a))dt||< \varepsilon$ Could you show me the demo, please.

Comment: If we have $\lVert x-a\rVert < \delta$ and $\lVert y-a\rVert < \delta$, then $\lVert (x + t(y-x)) - a\rVert < \delta$ for $t \in [0,1]$. Now you need $\bigl\lVert \int_0^1 g(t)\,dt\bigr\rVert \leqslant \int_0^1 \lVert g(t)\rVert\,dt$. Apply that to $g(t) = f'(x + t(y-x)) - f'(a)$.